# Workflow on update: get 'before' and 'after' values

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-online, update

The ODATA REST API on SharePoint online doesn't provide for querying for a specific version of a list item. I have an app that can only interact with this API.

Accordingly, for a list in which I need to be able to obtain values for past versions, it seems I need to roll my own 'history' by using a workflow triggered on update of items, which copies the record either to the same list, or another list, with a version number.

I can do this, but can't figure out how to obtain the 'before' values (the values prior to the change constituting the update) within the workflow where I'm setting column values.

How can I get these 'before' values in a workflow that is triggered in an update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to achieve this with a workflow is to have an "old" column of the changed column.

For example, let's say you have a column called `ColumnA` and another called `ColumnA_old`. `ColumnA_old` will be a *hidden* column.

Your workflow is triggered when an item is *changed*. The changed value will be in `ColumnA` and the original value will be in `ColumnA_old`. At some point in your workflow you must set the value of `ColumnA_old` to be equal to the value of `ColumnA`, ready for the next time the item is changed.

To avoid `ColumnA_old` being blank the first time the item is changed, you should have a second workflow set to start when the item is *created*, whose sole purpose is to set the value of `ColumnA_old` to `ColumnA`.

Alternatively, you can use a coded solution with the use of event receivers.

Comment: Many thanks, I think this will suit my needs in this particular case.