# Capture before and after values using SPD workflow

Tags: list, workflow, designer-workflow

In reference to the post here "[Workflow on update: get 'before' and 'after' values](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156575/workflow-on-update-get-before-and-after-values)", I'm looking to capture before and after values of a Status Column. The idea is to set a status date field to Current date when a status is changed. IF they revert the status back to old status, i want the old date in the date field. I can create a hidden column "OldStatus" that captures the Status when an item is created but the item is constantly modified as well using Access. So how do i capture status change when the item is modified?

Comment: Can you enable versioning on the list? The version history will show what values were changed and to what, as well as give you the option to roll back to a previous version.

Comment: Not sure how version history will help. This is a huge list with 30K items and users update more than 100 items at a time.